# Oracle Reports 6i - Rep 3300

Tags: oracle, report, oraclereports

While printing a report in batch i am getting the following error :**REP-3300 FATAL ERROR IN TOOLKIT - UI-9 THIS FUNCTION IS OUT OF CONTEXT**. My guess is the report is too large since its 10512 pages.

This error occurs while the report is in the previewer and the print is in session, the report is able to spool to the last page so i know the problem is not with the print spool size. I was able to print approximately 3500 pages and then the error was thrown.

I do not have administrator access to the machine i am printing the report from. I know the TEMP folder in the REPORT80 folder is restricted in size so i am assuming i need to generate smaller batches and then print.

I would like to know if there is a way to print this 10512 pages in parts like print the first 3000 pages then the next 3000..... until 10512. does oracle 6i reports provide any mechanism for printing in small amounts.

what i really want to achieve is when the user does the processing the report is thrown to the screen i want that to be 3000 records and when they close off the report previewer i want it to print another 3000 automatically without the users intervention.

Comment: When a user asks for a report that is 10,512 pages, just say "YAGNI". "You Ain't Gonna Need It" - because who is going to read 10,512 pages?

Comment: well its not to read but to print for companies customers but the user wants to know how many pages are being printed before had so they scroll to the end to get the number of pages

Comment: <facepalm> so they want to print it but not read it... makes perfect sense. Just print the first 100 pages, then put them on top of a stack of blank pages. :)

Comment: lol its hard to understand users at times. Think i would provide them with an option to indicate how many records they want in each run and limit it by 1000 records per transaction